# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when am try to open subview i put sound in the background

Tags: objective-c

i make subviewcontroller with three files .h .m .nib

the .h content :-

```
     @interface du3a : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {



}
```

the .m one is:-

```
    #import "du3a.h" 

@implementation du3a

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jaber" ofType:@"mp3"];

    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio; [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

the problem come from the mainview .m specially in this line :-

```
    -(IBAction)du3a:(id)sender {
    du3a *du3 = [[du3a alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:du3 animated:YES];


}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Try to put break points in `viewDidLoad` and figure out where the app crashes. Is the name of the mp3 correct?

Answer (score 1):

First: Do the `[super viewDidLoad];` at the beginning of the `viewDidLoad` method.

Second: Use the naming conventions.

Third: Your code seams to have leaks.

Comment: Hello dasdom, ths first option doesn't help me to figure out my problem , my code works great until am trying to add new subview with background sound .. am trying to change the name and problem still there , about the leaks let me post all code of my main view here .

Comment: -(IBAction)aqwalh:(id)sender {
        aqwalh *aqwal = [[aqwalh alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:aqwal animated:YES];
        
        
    }
    
    
    -(IBAction)sons:(id)sender {
        sons *son = [[sons alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:son animated:YES];
        
        
    }
    
    
    -(IBAction)du3a:(id)sender {
        du3a *du3 = [[du3a alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:du3 animated:YES];
       }